# JSLint 100% valid Google Universal Analytics snippet, fix "Unexpected assignment expression"

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, jslint, jshint

How to fix JSLint error ["Unexpected assignment expression"](http://jslinterrors.com/unexpected-assignment-expression) without breaking [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced) functionality?

The problematic line:

```
(w[g].q = w[g].q || []).push(arguments);
```

Full code:

```
<script src=//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js async></script>
<script>
/*global window: false, ga: false */
(function (w, g) {
    'use strict';

    w.GoogleAnalyticsObject = g;
    w[g] = w[g] || function () {
        (w[g].q = w[g].q || []).push(arguments);
    };
    w[g].l = +new Date();

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
}(window, 'ga'));
</script>
```

What has been done:

1. Avoided script-injected "async scripts" since [considered harmful](https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/)
2. Followed [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) suggestions

Comment: My advice, switch to JSHint.

Comment: Where do you define `arguments`? global? Looks to me you are creating an array with alot of undefined.

Comment: @BillyBlaze - `arguments` is not a global. It's created automatically inside any function and is an array-like object that contains references to the arguments passed into the function.

Comment: Thank you, I learned something new today. I also got some more info here http://www.sebarmeli.com/blog/2010/11/12/understanding-array-dot-prototype-dot-slice-dot-apply-arguments-in-javascript/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just split it into two lines:

```
w[g].q = w[g].q || [];
w[g].q.push(arguments);
```

This will work in the exact same way, it just makes the code a bit clearer. The first line checks whether `w[g].q` is truthy (presumably it will be `undefined` before the code first runs) and will assign an empty array to it if so.

This is a relatively common technique that is effectively shorthand for an `if` statement. If you want to make the code clearer still you could just use one of those:

```
if (!w[g].q) {
    w[g].q = [];
}
w[g].q.push(arguments);
```